# Knowing the initiator of a hashchange event

Tags: javascript, dom, jquery-events

I have a page with some links pointing to anchors and event handlers bound to the `hashchange` event:

```
<a href="#foo">Link</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).on('hashchange', function(e) {
        // Do something
    });
</script>
```

However, the event `e` has `Window` as its target.

Is there a way to determine what initiated the `hashchange` event, i.e. the link that was clicked?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit of a hack but still effective...  https://jsfiddle.net/bqbq4ust/1/

What I am doing is attaching the `hashchange` event when the user clicks the link..

```
<a href="#foo">Link</a>
<a href="#foo2">Link</a>


$(document).on('click', 'a[href*="#"]', function(e) {
  $(window)
    .off('hashchange.myNamespace')
    .one('hashchange.myNamespace', function(e2) {
      console.log(e);
      console.log(e2);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround is to check the hash with all the links on the page..

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(e) {
  var hash = location.hash;
  $('a').each(function() {
    var that = $(this);
    if (that.attr('href') === hash) {
      //that is the initiator
    }
  });
});
```